# Combining 3 arrays in one 3D array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, 3d, numpy

I have a very basic question regarding to arrays in numpy, but I cannot find a fast way to do it. I have three 2D arrays A,B,C with the same dimensions. I want to  convert these in one 3D array (D) where each element is an array

```
D[column][row] = [A[column][row] B[column][row] c[column][row]]
```

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [numpy.dstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.random((11, 13))
>>> b = np.random.random((11, 13))
>>> c = np.random.random((11, 13))
>>> 
>>> d = np.dstack([a,b,c])
>>> 
>>> d.shape
(11, 13, 3)
>>> 
>>> a[1,5], b[1,5], c[1,5]
(0.92522736614222956, 0.64294050918477097, 0.28230222357027068)
>>> d[1,5]
array([ 0.92522737,  0.64294051,  0.28230222])
```

Answer (score 7):

[numpy.dstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) stack the array along the third axis, so, if you stack 3 arrays (`a`, `b`, `c`) of shape `(N,M)`, you'll end up with an array of shape `(N,M,3)`.

An alternative is to use directly:

```
np.array([a, b, c])
```

That gives you a `(3,N,M)` array.

What's the difference between the two? The memory layout. You'll access your first array `a` as

```
np.dstack([a,b,c])[...,0]
```

or

```
np.array([a,b,c])[0]
```

Comment: Pierre, many thanks for your answer, I will test this option in my project. Actually, it doesn't matter in my project if is (N,M,3) or (3,N,M).