# Converting list of 2-D arrays into a 3-D array, adding elements along "fast" axes

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of 2d numpy arrays.  As a test, consider the following list:

```
lst = [np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)]*10
```

Now I can get at a particular data element by:

```
lst[k][j,i]
```

I would like to convert this to a numpy array so that I can index it:

```
array[k,j,i]
```

i.e., the shape should be `(10, 5, 2)`.

This seems to work, but seems completely unnecessary:

```
z = np.empty((10,5,2))
for i,x in enumerate(z):
    x[:,:] = lst[i]
```

These don't work:

```
np.hstack(lst)
np.vstack(lst)
np.dstack(lst)  #this is closest, but gives wrong shape (5, 2, 10)
```

I suppose I could pair a `np.dstack` with a `np.rollaxis`, but again, that doesn't seem quite right ...

Is there a good way to do this with numpy?

I've looked at [this very related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395420/combining-3-arrays-in-one-3d-array-in-numpy), but I can't quite seem to work it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work simply by calling the array constructor, i.e. `np.array(lst)`.

```
>>> l = [np.arange(10).reshape((5,2)) for i in range(10)]
>>> np.array(l).shape
(10, 5, 2)
```

Comment: right.  This is one of those moments when you just think to yourself -- "I should have known that!"

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like

```
>>> lst = [np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)]*10
>>> arr = np.array(lst)
>>> arr.shape
(10, 5, 2)
```

?

Comment: *sigh*.  I knew it would be an easy one.

Comment: @mgilson: four minutes ago I had no idea what you were talking about.  Now I do, and I guess this explains that unusual "Do you like hats?" or something box that popped up on my screen a while ago.. good luck! :^)

Comment: I found about it when I saw an answer by MartijnPieters, but his avatar had cheese on it's head ... I commented and you can imagine what happened from there. :).  As a side note, since I can't tell whether your answer was first or the other guy's, I'm gonna accept the other guy's since you're already a trusted user.  I hope you understand.  (I upvoted yours though if that's any consolation).

Comment: @mgilson: I beat him by twenty seconds or so [if you hover over the "answered X minutes ago", a little timebox should pop up], but no worries. :^)  People who seem to know what they're talking about should be upvoted to 2k ASAP anyhow!

Comment: I had a feeling you might have been first since you typically delete duplicate answers if someone beat you to it.  But, as you say, I think getting him to 2k is a worthwhile goal :).  Thanks for your service to the SO community (and I mean that very sincerely)